# magento2 afterpay payment method use Transaction has been declined. Please try again later?

Tags: magento2.3.7, afterpay

Transaction has been declined. Please try again later

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community we are using afterpay payment method when click on continue on afterpay  payment method using that time error show me  Transaction has been declined. Please try again later

Answer (score 0):

Please Check the Logs under var/logs folder. debug.log exception.log and system.log. Hope you find some info there.

Comment: [2022-06-01 09:52:08] main.CRITICAL: Payment Error: unauthorized [] []
[2022-06-01 09:52:08] main.CRITICAL: Payment Error: Credentials are required to access this resource. [] []

Comment: I think the required Payment info is not being provided . Is it a Custom payment or you are doing some customization task in a Third Party Module?

Comment: but before few day working fine